# Concatenate and keep the cell format in excel

Tags: excel, format

I have a column of cells in a special format where I need to keep the leading 0. I'm trying to concatenate these cells with a bunch of other cells, but I keep losing the cell format. Any ideas to keep the cell's special format in the concatenation? The cell has a special format to add a 0 sometimes, but not all cells have a leading 0. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Use [`TEXT`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/text-function-20d5ac4d-7b94-49fd-bb38-93d29371225c) within your concatenation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, "reapply" the special format to the cell's value as you are concatenating, using the [`TEXT` function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/text-function-20d5ac4d-7b94-49fd-bb38-93d29371225c).

Here's sample data, with the concatenation starting in `C2`:

```
=TEXT(A2,"0000")&B2
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't help/work. Its still dropping the leading zero off the concatenated cell. The special cell is in the Special: Portuguese(Angola) language, with a sample of "075232173"

Answer (score 0):

[image: If this helps, this shows the format of the cell, and if you see above the box, the right most cell still shows it without the leading zero]

If this helps, this shows the format of the cell, and if you see above the box, the right most cell still shows it without the leading zero

Comment: What is the formula you used in the far right cell?

Comment: I used this: =TEXT(B10, "0000")&A10

Comment: "0000" was just a sample and would not work in your case - you need at least "000000000" - at least nine zeros.